# is there a simple way to create a black version of a ccsprite for a CCSpriteBatchNode?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I was hoping I could just do:

```
sprite.color = cc3(0, 0, 0);
```

But, that does not seem to work.

Comment: what specifically is the relationship between the line of code and `CCSpribeBatchNode` ?  i am assuming a cocos2d 2.x variant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use shader

Take a look at this project: https://github.com/slembcke/Cocos2DShaderCookbook

Comment: If you want to use cocos2d v2, you can check this tutorial for shaders: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4428/how-to-mask-a-sprite-with-cocos2d-2-0

Comment: Yeah, I saw that tutorial previously and tried following it, but I was never seeing the shader work on my sprite.  I am unclear on if you can use these shaders with sprites that are children of CCSpriteBatchNodes?